# How do I debug last line of context?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

When I set a breakpoint on the last line of a context it jumps before I get the return value.

For instance if I have a function like:

```
function SomeFunc(){

    // some stuff going on

    $value = ThisReturnsAValue();  // breakpoint set on this line
}
```

I don't get to see the value of `$value` before it jumps out of context.

What I am finding myself doing is adding in another variable just so I can break after the value is returned like this:

```
function SomeFunc(){

    // some stuff going on

    $value = ThisReturnsAValue();  
    $foo = '';  // breakpoint now set on this line
}
```

Then `$value` is available to look at in my watches.

This feels wrong.  Is there an option somewhere to evaluate the last line before leaving the context?

(I am using PHPStorm & Xdebug)

Comment: Set the Breakpoint to the last }. Most Debugger support that (NetBeans does)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a solution for this. I'm doing the same thing.

I'm even doing things like:

```
$return = $this->doStuff();
return $return;
```

Just to see the return value right before returning.

There are options for setting different type of breakpoints in IntelliJ, but they are not available in PHPStorm / for PHP. My guess is due to limitations of XDebug or they haven't gotten around to it yet.

Until then, you might get a bit nearer to what you want by using a `conditional breakpoint`. Just set a breakpoint as normal, rightclick on the red bullet and add your condition. It will now happily continue when the condition is not met.